# Linq to XML elements and descendants in the same search

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Still learning Linq and had a problem trying to retrieve and element as well as descendants of another in the same select. I searched for a solution, but could not find what I was looking for and came up with a solution. But is it the right way to do it? Somehow, although it works, it does feel right.

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Tables>
    <Table>
        <SourceTable>WrittenRecordsTable</SourceTable>
        <Researcher>Fred Blogs</Researcher>
        <QuickRef>cwr</QuickRef>
        <TableType>WrittenRecords</TableType>
        <FieldMapping>
            <RecordID>ID</RecordID>
            <StartYear>StartYear</StartYear>
            <EndYear>EndYear</EndYear>
            <LastName>LastName</LastName>
            <Title>Title</Title>
            <Subject>Subject</Subject>
            <Description>Reference</Description>
        </FieldMapping>
    </Table>
</Tables>
```

and the following Linq to XML:

```
var nodes = (from n in xml.Descendants("FieldMapping")
            select new
            {
                SourceTable = (string)n.Parent.Element("SourceTable").Value,
                RecordID = (string)n.Element("RecordID").Value,
                StartYear = (string)n.Element("StartYear").Value,
                EndYear = (string)n.Element("EndYear").Value,
                LastName = (string)n.Element("LastName").Value,
                Title = (string)n.Element("Title").Value,
                Subject = (string)n.Element("Subject").Value
             }).ToList();
```

It is the way I retrieve the **SourceTable** element that feels wrong. Am I worrying too much or is there a better way? Also, is it better to work with c# expressions rather than queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your document structure always has to contain those nodes your query (and accessing `SourceTable`) is fine. It's fairly obvious of what's going on given reader knows how XML looks like.

However, if you want more top-down approach (which might *seem* more natural and easier to grasp), you can always query `Table` node first and store `FieldMapping` in a variable, but I wouldn't say it has any advantages over your approach:

```
var nodes = (from table in doc.Descendants("Table")
             let fieldMapping = table.Element("FieldMapping")
             select new
             {
                 SourceTable = (string)table.Element("SourceTable").Value,
                 RecordID = (string)fieldMapping.Element("RecordID").Value,
                 StartYear = (string)fieldMapping.Element("StartYear").Value,
                 EndYear = (string)fieldMapping.Element("EndYear").Value,
                 LastName = (string)fieldMapping.Element("LastName").Value,
                 Title = (string)fieldMapping.Element("Title").Value,
                 Subject = (string)fieldMapping.Element("Subject").Value
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's great, thanks @jimmy_keen. I can see the approach, but as you suggest, it does not really gain anything. As it is working, I will leave as is for now.